# Only retrieving journeys without tags via REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to retrieve journey information with REST API in Marketing Cloud.
According to the "Search Journeys - GET /interaction/v1/interactions" page, there is tag as URL Parameters to filter results by tags.

(FYI, https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getInteractionCollection.htm)

I would like to get only the journeys without tags, if possible.
Does anybody know how to write URL parameter in this case?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have marketing cloud license to try this, but try sending blank value in tag like this `/interaction/v1/interactions?tag=&$page=2&$pageSize=2` or `/interaction/v1/interactions?tag&$page=2&$pageSize=2`

I think passing params without value should be treated as null.

or if the above does not work try with `/interaction/v1/interactions?tag=%00&$page=2&$pageSize=2`

`%00` is a URLEncoded NUL value.